# Modular Arithmetic - Division

Tags: algorithm, modular-arithmetic

How does one calculate (a/b) % m where a = x1*x2*.... and the numbers x1, x2,.. are quite large.

If we only had to find a % m , we could have easily done that using (x1%m) * (x2%m) *... but if there's something in the denominator 'b' in our case, how does one go about calculating it ?

I read somewhere this being done as (a % (m*b)) / b . I have been wondering if this is true and how do we go about proving it ?

Comment: Is *m* (known to be) a prime number by any chance? That makes the calculation simpler.

Comment: Is b known to be a factor of a?  Else, is it correct to assume integer division?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens. The value of m is not known. I was wondering if this was true for the general case.

Comment: but as @JohnBollinger suggested ! yes it seems the simple formula is only true if b is a factor of a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get at least this far:

```
b * ((a / b) % m) = (b * (a / b)) % (b * m)
                  = (a - (a % b)) % (b * m)
                  = (a % (b * m) - (a % b) % (b * m))
                  = (a % (b * m) - (a % b))

hence,

((a / b) % m) = ((a % (b * m)) - (a % b)) / b
```

That is already easier to compute, hence I justify giving this as an answer.  I *think* you can go on from there to the simpler formula you suggested, but I haven't the time or inclination to work that out.  (So if this is homework then I leave a bit of it for you to do yourself :))